# How to get JSON value from varchar field

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

*outdated Oracle version

I have a table for receipt data.
I want to get some data from field EXT_ATTR. such as PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO

The field "EXT_ATTR" is varchar(4000) stored JSON value

```
SerialId    |  EXT_ATTR

 1          |  

{
    "PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO": "PS00000000000000001",
    "IS_CORPOR": "1",
    "POSTCODE1": "51000",
    "POSTCODE2": "51000",
    "BILLADDR1PART1": "BILLADDR1PART1_DATA",
    "BILLADDR1PART2": "BILLADDR1PART2_DATA",
    "NEED_PRINT_WHT": "1",
    "WHT_AMT": "0",
    "TRXAMT": "2340600",
    "LOCATIONID": "02140",
    "PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME": "Cash",
    "WITH_TAX": "1"
}

2           |  

{
    "PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO": "PS00000000000000055",
    "IS_CORPOR": "1",
    "POSTCODE1": "51000",
    "POSTCODE2": "51000",
    "BILLADDR1PART1": "BILLADDR1PART1_DATA",
    "BILLADDR1PART2": "BILLADDR1PART2_DATA",
    "NEED_PRINT_WHT": "1",
    "WHT_AMT": "0",
    "TRXAMT": "2340600",
    "LOCATIONID": "02140",
    "PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME": "Cash",
    "WITH_TAX": "1"
}
```

How can I extract varchar filed to get only value.

```
SerialId    |  PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO

1           |  PS00000000000000001

2           |  PS00000000000000055
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

to work with json documents you can use [`PL/JSON`](https://github.com/pljson/pljson)

if you want to parse it without json Tools, than you can use substr, instr function in Oracle.
depending on what your string looks like, you have to adjust string positions.

> ```
> create table tab (json varchar2(1000));
> ```

> ```
> insert into tab values('{"PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO": "PS00000000000000001","IS_CORPOR": "1","POSTCODE1": "51000","POSTCODE2": "51000","BILLADDR1PART1": "BILLADDR1PART1_DATA","BILLADDR1PART2": "BILLADDR1PART2_DATA","NEED_PRINT_WHT": "1","WHT_AMT": "0","TRXAMT": "2340600","LOCATIONID": "02140","PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME": "Cash","WITH_TAX": "1"}');
> ```

> ```
> insert into tab values('{"PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO": "PS00000000000000055","IS_CORPOR": "1","POSTCODE1": "51000","POSTCODE2": "51000","BILLADDR1PART1": "BILLADDR1PART1_DATA","BILLADDR1PART2": "BILLADDR1PART2_DATA","NEED_PRINT_WHT": "1","WHT_AMT": "0","TRXAMT": "2340600","LOCATIONID": "02140","PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME": "Cash","WITH_TAX": "1"}');
> ```

> ```
> select substr(json,instr(json,': ',1,1)+3,instr(json,',',1,1)-instr(json,': ',1,1)-4)
> from tab;
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTR(JSON,INSTR(JSON,':',1,1)+3,INSTR(JSON,',',1,1)-INSTR(JSON,':',1,1)-4) |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | PS00000000000000001                                                          |
> | PS00000000000000055                                                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7bb824c2a71238557baca0932c29ff09)*

Answer (score 0):

**JSON** functions are defined for `Database Oracle12c+` version. `APEX_JSON` package with release `5.0+` should be installed for the previous releases. Whenever installation complete, then the following code might be used as an **XML** data type manner through `APEX_JSON.TO_XMLTYPE()` function in order to extract the desired values :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT SerialId, APEX_JSON.TO_XMLTYPE(Payment_Receipt_No) AS xml_data
  FROM tab
)
SELECT SerialId, Payment_Receipt_No
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE('/json'
                PASSING xml_data
                COLUMNS 
                  Payment_Receipt_No VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO'
               )
```